# how to update the form field automatically

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am developing a task management system in that i am having the age field in registration form i am having doubt about how to update the field automatically when i click.
my script is

```
<script>
    var a = document.age1.dob.value;
    age = a.getFullYear();
    var curr = new Date();
    year = curr.getFullYear();
    var age1 = year - age;
</script>
```

i calculated the age and stored it in `age1` variable.

```
<form id="form2" action="#" method="post" name="age1">
<h4><b>Register here</b></h4>
<b>Name</b>: <input type="text" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Your name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+"><br><br>
<b>E-mail</b>: <input type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="someone@example.com" pattern="[a-z0-9._+%-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"><br><br>
<b>Password</b>: <input type="password" name="password" required="required"><br><br>
<b>DOB</b>: <input type="text" name="dob" required placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" pattern="^[0-3]?[0-9].[0-3]?[0-9].(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$"><br><br>
<b>Age</b>: <input type="text" name="age" id="age2"><br><br>
<b>Address</b>: <textarea name="address" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea>
<button id="butr" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Signup</button>
```

[image]

After i input my DOB in the registration form and click the age field i want the calculated age that i stored it in `age1` variable to automatically update the value in age field that i have it in my registration form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an onchange function to dob field

```
<input type="text" onchange="ageCalculation()" name="dob">
```

Add this code in your `<script>`

```
function ageCalculation(){  
 if(document.age1.dob.value!==""){
     var a = document.age1.dob.value;
     a=new Date(a);
    age = a.getFullYear();
    var curr = new Date();
    year = curr.getFullYear();
    var age1 = year - age;
    document.age1.age.value=age1;
 }
}
```

Comment: You should also do a validation of the input so that it is a valid date but otherwise this is exactly what I started writing, but I was not fast enough. :)

Comment: i included the ageCalculation function but it doesn't work

Comment: @Sree — I am amazed… We were told ages ago to deport JS code from html structure. pkarthicbz's html style shows an utter ignorance of good practices and you are encouraging him in the wrong direction. Clearly your function is correct, but your getting at DOM elements the way HE does shall bring him no enlightment.

Comment: @pkarthicbz : Did you add onchange event ? `<input type="text" onchange="ageCalculation()" name="dob">`

Comment: @BriceCoustillas : As he mentioned only javascript tag I used that method. If jQuery was there I could do better :)

Comment: don't need to add `Date(a)`. it's working fine without it.Thank you @Sree

Comment: @pkarthicbz No problem . Glad to help :)